# How to subscribe a Pubnub channel asynchronous?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, pubnub

I want my rails app to subscribe a global channel, so everything happens on client, then client will publish into that channel. I want it to be asynchronous because there will be a lot of messages via that channels, and I want it to run along with Rails process. Currently, I can't get it to work, I put it `initializers/pubnub.rb`:

```
$pubnub.subscribe(channel: 'global', callback: ->(envelop) { do_something })
```

I don't get any incoming messages.

Comment: If you subscribe with the demo keys (demo/demo) and subscribe to channel 'bot', do you receive anything?

Answer (score 0):

Just an usage example in my test app:

```
$pubnub = Pubnub.new(
  :subscribe_key => "demo",
  :publish_key   => "demo",
  :heartbeat     => 10,
  :logger        => Rails.logger
)

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection

$pubnub.subscribe(:channel => :demo){|e| Message.create(:content => e.msg)}
```

It works just fine. What code You are trying to run in the callback?